# ViewController UIwebview issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I am new to xcode so I was following a tutorial about putting a webpage into an ios objective-c project in xcode 7. Below is the code I use.
    @interface ViewController ()

View controller header

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end

view controller main
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@synthesize webView;

@end
```

The bug warnings are;

1.Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol'

2.Attribute can only be applied to instance variables or properties

And both apply to the first line starting with IBOutlet

Comment: do you use storyboards? or do you want to add the webview programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for **instance variables** Just missing {}

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
  IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

but actually the declaration **can be skipped**
eg.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

This line

```
@synthesize webView;
```

should put below @implementation for consistency, and can **skip** as well

(after Xcode 4.4 the compiler will generate for u, but it's good to know the original code)

more about class:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html